# How to tell if ffmpeg errored or not?

Tags: ffmpeg

**The Situation:**
I'm using ffmpeg (via .net) to save video files. I can get the output from ffmpeg but I dont know how can I customize the output to have better result.

**My Problem:**
My problem is, there is no certain difference between successful and failed operation.

> **last line of success:**
>
> video:1006kB audio:134kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.943510%
>
> **last lines from fails**
>
> c:\x\test-9-8/30/2012-9:29:56-AM.mp4: Invalid argument
>
> rtmp://cdn.tv/cdn-live39/*definst*/stream01: Unknown error occurred

**My Question:**
Is there an option (or command line parameter) to add some sort of return code (200: success, 500: error, etc)

Thanks!

PS: I saw this topic [How to tell if ffmpeg errored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390720/how-to-tell-if-ffmpeg-errored?rq=1) but there is no number before/after last line. I think the last version doesnt have number anymore.

Comment: I've an idea (not ideal solution).. I can check the target file for exist or not when all the process is done. if the file is exist and bigger than zero byte I would assume the process was successful. If the target file not exist get last line of the output and show it as error message..

Comment: not a good solution. Did that, because I thought naïvely "ffmpeg won't create, or at least keep, the output file if there is an error", but it does. Check exist status = 0 means everything is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is very old but as i came across and found no other reliable answer and after some more testing:

The suggestion with checking for return of 0 is in general a good advice - but does not help in all cases. The other idea with checking if the file exists is also good - but again - does not help in all cases.

For example when the input file is a mp3 file that has an embedded cover - then ffmpeg does (in my tests) use this image and extracts that one as an (unusable) video file.

What i do now is to have debug level output and parse it for the number of muxed packets.

`ffmpeg -i "wildlife.mp4" -c:v copy -an -sn "out.mp4" -y -loglevel debug 2> wildlife.txt`

With a regex i search for this text:
`Output stream .+ (video): [0-9][0-9]+ packets muxed \([0-9][0-9]+ bytes\)`

(this assumes that every video has more than 9 packets - could of course be optimized for really short videos).

Of course for RTMP or other settings the output may differ but i think to parse the full output stream is the only option.

Comment: is there an extensive list of cases in which the return or the file fail to check for errors?

Answer (score 5):

You could just check the exit code returned by ffmpeg. It should return 0 on success, anything else means it failed.

Comment: Is this guaranteed to be reliable?

Comment: This does not work. FFmpeg does not (always) return non 0 on errors

Comment: @DIDoS Can you give an example?

Comment: how do i check that why it failed? I have added the ffmpeg as library simple tried to follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683960/android-video-encoding-with-fr-and-resolution-manipulation/23815402#23815402

Comment: @ArpanSharma That question is for using ffmpeg as executable, not as library. But you can [ask a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for libraries.

Comment: @sashoalm I just have to compress a video before uploading in my android app. whatever way that seems fit.Can you guide me please

Comment: @ArpanSharma [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: is there an extensive list of cases in which this return fail to check for errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can run ffmpeg in `-v error` mode and have it return errors into a text file, see here: https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4 You can combine this with encoding without the `null` output but you will only be able to read the results from the text file.

Or you can have an additional script that will follow-up on the errors. Here is a Python example, which checks for file integrity, notice the `if stdout` clause. This will basically re-check encoded file if you need to see normal output first.

**Solution 1:**

```py
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import re

def check_video(files):
    if type(files) == str:
        files = [files]

    for file in files:
        print(f"Checking {file}...")
        command_line = f'ffmpeg -v error -i "{file}" -map 0:v -map 0:a? -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f null -'
        base_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]

        process = subprocess.Popen(command_line, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
        return_code = process.returncode
        pid = process.pid

        print(f"Base: {base_name}")
        print(f"Extension: {extension}")
        print(f"RC: {return_code}")

        if stdout:
            allowed_errs = ["invalid as first byte of an EBML number"]
            stdout_detect = stdout.decode().split("\n")

            for error in allowed_errs:
                if error not in stdout_detect[0] or len(stdout_detect) > 2:
                    print(f"Errors!")
                    print(os.path.splitext(file)[1])
                    os.rename(file, f"{file}.error")
                    with open(f"{file}.error.log", "w") as errfile:
                        if stdout:
                            errfile.write(stdout.decode())
                        if stderr:
                            errfile.write(stderr.decode())
                else:
                    print("Minor problems detected.")
        else:
            print("File OK.")


        process.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = sys.argv[1:]
    # files = ["a.mkv"]
    check_video(files)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
        with subprocess.Popen(command_line,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                              universal_newlines=True) as self.process:

            for line in self.process.stdout:
                print(line, end='')

        return_code = self.process.wait()
```

From here, you can do whatever you like with each `line`, like checking for error keywords in them. I think ffmpeg has some standard of error reporting (https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__error.html). With this solution, output will be displayed to you same as with directly running ffmpeg. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4417735/1793606. Tested with Python 3.10

**Solution 3:**
Also, you can set `err_detect` for ffmpeg itself, that should reflect in the return code

Answer (score 0):

The global option `-xerror`: Stop and exit on error.

Using it, an exit code of `0` indicates there has been no error.

Source: [ffmpeg Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)